# handling null values when calculating average?

Tags: vb.net, null

I'm trying to calculate the average of bidprice but sometimes it has null values. the code i have is:

```
 Private Sub count()
    Dim sum As Decimal
    Dim dgvr As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow
    For Each dgvr In Me.CustAgentListDataGridView.Rows
        sum += dgvr.Cells("Price").Value
    Next dgvr
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Me.CustAgentListDataGridView.Rows.Count
    Dim avg As Decimal
    If (n > 0) Then
        avg = sum / n
    Else
        avg = 0
    End If
    txtavgbidprice.Text = avg.ToString("$ 0.00")
End Sub
```

Comment: Check for `Is Nothing` before adding `Value` to `sum`, by placing the `sum += ...` line in an `if`-statement, and also subtract the number of nulls from `n` to get a correct average.

Comment: If you are using a DataTable you can have it `Compute` that sort of thing for you...otherwise test for DBNull

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Is the grid bound to a data source and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the cleaned up code below... I commented through-out so you could see the differences...

**Code Tried and Tested**

```
 Private Sub count()
    Dim sum As Decimal
    Dim nDec As Decimal
    For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow In Me.CustAgentListDataGridView.Rows
       If Not dgvr.IsNewRow AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(dgvr.Cells("Price").Value.ToString,nDec) Then 'make sure it's not a new row and we can parse out the value into the correct type...
          sum += CDec(dgvr.Cells("Price").Value)
       End If            
    Next

    'if we have a sum, then we should have some rows...
    Dim avg As Decimal
    If sum > 0 Then
        avg = sum / CustAgentListDataGridView.Rows.Count
        txtavgbidprice.Text = avg.ToString("$ 0.00")
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is a `Linq` approach where we cast each row out, make sure it's not null and it's not a new row and finally get the average...

```
txtavgbidprice.Text = CDec(DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Where(Function(x) x.Cells("Price").Value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso Not x.IsNewRow).Average(Function(r) CDec(r.Cells("Price").Value))).ToString("$ 0.00")
```